# How to get the sum of values inside Struts 2 iterator?

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, ognl, valuestack

My application is shopping website application. In place order case, I need to pass the sum of every item's price as a one parameter. Prices are coming to the iterator correctly. But I failed to get the sum of those prices. shopping cart list is coming from Another action class.

I tried with this:

```
<s:iterator value="shoppingCarts" var="shoppingCarts">      
   <s:label name="total" value="%{#total+(item.salesPrice*qty)+item.shippingCost}" label="Total"/>
</s:iterator>
```

This shows two labels, if shopping cart list has two items. How can I get a total to a one parameter inside the iterator?

Comment: it's unclear what you mean by shopping cart list. Post the code with structure.

Comment: that is the list I need to pass to the action class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a context variable `total` like in this exampe

```
<s:set var="total" value="0">
<s:iterator value="shoppingCarts">
  s:set var="total" value="%{#total+item.salesPrice*qty+item.shippingCost}"/>         
</s:iterator>
<s:label name="total" value="%{#total}" label="Total"/>
```